# Column Resize CSS or HTML

Tags: html, css

I have a table that I am trying to remove the spacing around the word "MENU" but have been unsuccessful. Here is the code I am using:

```html
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">

<head>
  <meta content="text/html; charset=utf-8" http-equiv="Content-Type" />
  <title>Peer Review</title>
</head>
<style type="text/css">
  #test {
    transform: rotate(-90deg);
    font-family: HelveticaNeue, Helvetica Neue, Helvetica, Arial, sans-serif;
    font-size: 14pt;
    color: black;
    font-weight: bold;
    margin: 0px 0px 0px 0px;
    right: 0px;
    padding: 0px 0px 0px 0px
  }
  table.nospacing {
    border-spacing: 0;
  }
  table.nospacing th,
  td {
    padding: 0;
  }
</style>

<body>
  <table class="nospacing" style="border-style:none;background-color:aqua">
    <tr>
      <td>
        <ul>
          <li>&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;Review</li>
          <li><a href="#">&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;Home</a>
          </li>
          <li><a href="#">&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;About</a>
          </li>
          <li><a href="#">&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;Contacts</a>
          </li>
          <li><a href="#">&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;FAQs</a>
          </li>
        </ul>
        <hr width="200px" />
        <ul style="position:relative">
          <li><a href="#">&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;Products</a>
          </li>
          <li><a href="#">&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;Report</a>
          </li>
          <li><a href="#">&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;Periodic</a>
          </li>
          <li><a href="#">&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;Guide</a>
          </li>

        </ul>
        <ul>
          <!-- #BeginEditable "redlines" -->
          <li style="display:none"><a href="#">&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;Redlines</a>
          </li>
          <!-- #EndEditable -->
        </ul>
      </td>
      <td style="border-left:medium;border-left-color:white;border-left-style:solid">
        <p id="test">MENU</p>
      </td>

    </tr>
  </table>


</body>

</html>
​
```

How can I shrink the right column's width? I have tried setting padding, widths, etc to no avail.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Please check this Code and if you need any desired width you can change max-width.

```css
 #test {
    transform: rotate(-90deg);
    font-family: HelveticaNeue, Helvetica Neue, Helvetica, Arial, sans-serif;
    font-size: 14pt;
    color: black;
    font-weight: bold;
    margin: 0px 0px 0px 0px;
    right: 0px;
    padding: 0px 0px 0px 0px
  }
  table.nospacing {
    border-collapse: collapse;
 border-spacing: 0;
    table-layout: fixed;
  }
  table.nospacing th,
  td {
    padding: 0;
  }
.menu-col{max-width: 30px;}
```

```html
<table class="nospacing" style="border-style:none;background-color:aqua">
    <tr>
      <td>
        <ul>
          <li>&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;Review</li>
          <li><a href="#">&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;Home</a>
          </li>
          <li><a href="#">&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;About</a>
          </li>
          <li><a href="#">&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;Contacts</a>
          </li>
          <li><a href="#">&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;FAQs</a>
          </li>
        </ul>
        <hr width="200px" />
        <ul style="position:relative">
          <li><a href="#">&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;Products</a>
          </li>
          <li><a href="#">&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;Report</a>
          </li>
          <li><a href="#">&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;Periodic</a>
          </li>
          <li><a href="#">&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;Guide</a>
          </li>

        </ul>
        <ul>
          <!-- #BeginEditable "redlines" -->
          <li style="display:none"><a href="#">&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;Redlines</a>
          </li>
          <!-- #EndEditable -->
        </ul>
      </td>
      <td class="menu-col" style="border-left:medium;border-left-color:white;border-left-style:solid">
        <p id="test">MENU</p>
      </td>

    </tr>
  </table>
```

Comment: you welcome... you can fix width for one td of each ser via % or px

Answer (score 0):

The reason for that, is that the columns width depends on the width of the column-content (in your case the p-tag with 'menu'). The width of the column just ignores that you rotated it.
If you want to fix that you have to either change the width of the p-tag or set a max-width on the column.

```
#test {
  /* Your code */
  width: 40px;
}
```

But be aware that this will "uncenter" the menu text. To replace it try `transform: translateX`.

Comment: Thanks for the explanation. The code above fixed the problem and now I know why.